# ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) User does not have permission to access project (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm looking to put together a script that I can run from Cloud Shell to enable an API in all projects. It is successfully going through each project, but I am getting a permission denied message for every one. I am the owner so there shouldn't be any permission issues.

As a permission test, if I run just "gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com", the API successfully enables.

What am I missing?

```
#!/bin/bash
for project in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
do
    echo "ProjectId:  $project"
    for enableapi in $(gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com list --project $project --format=list)
     do
        echo "    -> Enabled $enableapi"
    done
done
```

Comment: You specified cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com AND list as services. "list" is not a service!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lucas, this way could work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for project in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
do
    echo "ProjectId:  $project"
    gcloud config set project $project
    gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com  --project $project
done
```

I'm following [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api).

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to set the project config if you use the --project flag to enable a service. The real problem is that you want to enable multiple services in your bash script, including a service called "list", which does not exists. Here is how to properly enable multiple api at the same time:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure this is a valid bash array!
services=(service1 service2 service3)

# Option 1
for project in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
do
    gcloud services enable $services --project $project
done

# Option 2
for project in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
do
    for service in $services
    do
        gcloud services enable $service --project $project
    done
done
```

See [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable) documentation.