# gas-local Reference Err SpreadsheetApp is not defined

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script

I'm trying to set up my app script project using [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) and test it locally using [gas-local](https://github.com/mzagorny/gas-local), I have reached the step of testing but I got this error `ReferenceError: SpreadsheetApp is not defined`.

*gas.js*

```
 //require gas-local itself
 var gas = require('gas-local');
 //require your downloaded google apps script library from src subfolder  
 var glib = gas.require('./src');
```

where src is my google app script project folder, however when I `node gas` I got the `ReferenceError: SpreadsheetApp is not defined`

**The idea from using gas-local is that I want to know my GAS cloudProject ID programatically, so I thought I would trigger any method locally and get the project-id from the error message that will be thrown.**

I would appreciate anyone writes a step by step guide with screenshots if possible showing how to accomplish this process.

Comment: You need to write your mock simulating `SpreadsheetApp` with all the functions inside. See readme of gas-local for the custom mockup of MailApp.getRemaingQuota().

Comment: @TheMaster so it will not be like the real SpreadsheetApp? I need it to be like the real one so that I can get GAS cloudProject ID programmatically.

Comment: That's a completely different question and better asked in a different post. Why do you want to retrieve the project-id programmatically?

Comment: @TheMaster to enable the required services programmatically like "gcloud services enable drive.googleapis.com" so that I can test my methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757388/

Comment: @TheMaster thanks for helping, but this answers how to get a standard GCP project; I want the default project that is created for Apps Script projects- which it doesn't appear in that list unfortunately